# Trying to create new product type in magento, getting fatal error

Tags: custom-product-type

I'm trying to create new product type in magento and it is showing up in admin panel create new product page's product type options, but when I select it and continue, i get fatal error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function setConfig() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\gift\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type.php on line 80

Comment: Please have a look on these answers and report back with more informations: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 2):

Each product type must have a 'type instance' model associated to it.
For example the simple products have this type instance `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple`, configurable have `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable` and so on.
Most probably in your case the type instance model is not declared or does not exist.
See in `config.xml` of the catalog module how you should declare your product type in the path `catalog/product/type`.
Here is how the configurable product is declared

```
               <configurable translate="label" module="catalog"> <!-- unique tag - type name --> 
                    <label>Configurable Product</label> <!-- label for the form type dropdown -->
                    <model>catalog/product_type_configurable</model><!-- type model - this is what is missing for you probably -->
                    <price_model>catalog/product_type_configurable_price</price_model><!-- price model class -->
                    <composite>1</composite><!-- is composite or not -->
                    <allow_product_types> <!-- allowed types in composite products. you may not need this -->
                        <simple/>
                        <virtual/>
                    </allow_product_types>
                    <index_priority>30</index_priority><!-- sort order in the admin dropdown -->
                    <price_indexer>catalog/product_indexer_price_configurable</price_indexer><!-- indexer class for price index -->
                </configurable>
```